# Excel concatenate formula formatting for numbers

Tags: excel, formatting, numbers, concatenation

if I've used two separate formulas using concatenate into one cell and both or one brings answer with decimals, how can I format to limit or remove (roundoff) the result numbers?

Here's the formula: =CONCATENATE((F2/4.2),"/",((F2/4.2)/7))
and here's the example result: 273.809523809524/39.1156462585034

Now, for me, the idea solution is that the cell shows 234/39. Basically how (if at all) can I format that cell with concatenate formula?

thanks.

Comment: Use the *ROUND()* function in your formula.

Comment: How do you go from getting 273.8 in your example formula to needing 234?

Comment: I've no idea how. Can you pls help me write the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=CONCATENATE(ROUND(F2/4.2,0),"/",ROUND((F2/4.2)/7,0))`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.